# Tyrion Lannister Acquits Himself? Guess Again!

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

If I were to say that, in his [**perilous negotiations**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwnK_glEhSw) with the slavers (*transcribed below*), Tyrion Lannister had “acquitted” himself, would I be saying that Tyrion had **A)** repaid or settled a debt or obligation incurred (i.e., the insult of the slaver’s disparaging assumption) or **B)** conducted himself in a *specified* manner? Either sense seems plausible, but not both in the instant case.

Prior to my inquiry I was unfamiliar with sense **(A)**. On the few occasions I’ve encountered the usage of “acquit” outside of the legal sense of being found “not guilty,” it has always collocated with “well,” as in the latter sense **(B)** and the lexicons I’ve consulted fail to specify the conduct. Is it even possible to “acquit oneself” other than adroitly (well)?

**Scene: Boss Slaver and his Lieutenant discussing the fate of their captives**

> **Lt. Slaver:** (indicating Jorah Mormont) Salt mines?
>
> **Boss Slaver:** That ... or a galley-slave. He looks strong enough.
>
> **Lt. Slaver:** What about the dwarf?
>
> **Boss Slaver:** Worthless. Cut his throat.
>
> **Tyrion:** Wait. Wait. Wait, wait, wait! Let’s discuss this!
>
> **Boss Slaver:** And then ... chop off his cock. We’ll sell it for a fortune ... a dwarf’s cock has magic powers.
>
> **Tyrion:** Wait. Wait. Wait, wait, wait! You can’t just hand a dried cock to a merchant and expect him to pay for it! He has ta know it came from a dwarf! And how could he know, unless he sees the dwarf?
>
> **Lt. Slaver:** It will be a dwarf-sized cock.
>
> **Tyrion:** Guess again!

[**ACQUIT**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/acquit)

Collins defines "acquit" thusly:

> **acquit** vb (tr):
>
> **3**. to repay or settle (something, such as a debt or obligation)
>
> **4**. to perform (one's part); conduct (oneself)
>
> [C13: from Old French *aquiter*, from *quiter* to release, free from, quit]

Whereas, the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language defines **acquit**:

> **2**. To conduct (oneself) in a specified manner: acquitted herself well during the interview.
>
> **3**. *Archaic* To release or discharge from an obligation, such as a debt.
>
> **4**. *Obsolete* To repay.
>
> [Middle English *aquiten*, from Old French *aquiter*: a-, to (from Latin ad-; see quite in Indo-European roots).] Definitions/etymology from **TFD**

**SPOILER ALERT:** Tyrion manages to hold on to his genitalia ... so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my search of Google Books, I came across references to acquitting oneself not only "well" or "honorably", but "creditably", "better than the others". "adequately", and  even "badly".  So there are definitely degrees.

That said, it seems two things are clear:

1)  The usage of "acquit himself" has been declining rather steadily since its zenith (circa 1700), see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acquit%20himself&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacquit%20himself%3B%2Cc0).

2) "Acquit oneself" seems to have had a third sense, (perhaps derived from the "debt" one), which seems wider, and very much like  "rid oneself of": to acquit oneself of a duty, of a foolish notion, or of whatever thing one wants to be rid of. Sort of like how one can use *quitar* in Spanish to describe anything from taking off your clothes to abandoning a relationship.

Sorry I couldn't paste in some examples, but here's the [link](https://www.google.it/search?q=acquit%20himself&biw=320&bih=416&tbm=bks&ei=cO9vVaz5PIbYsAXT-oHgBw&start=30&sa=N&dpr=1&gws_rd=cr).

Answer (score 0):

For your third sense, [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/acquit) tells us that the idiom is:

> (acquit oneself of) *archaic* Discharge (a duty or responsibility):
>
> *they acquitted themselves of their charge with vigilance*

---

PS- I don't think using `acquit` here makes sense. I think Tyrion was just saving his skin, which isn't much of a 'responsibility', per se; nor a repayment or a settlement. `acquit` could be used in other cases, though. Say, if Ser Jorah saved Tyrion from the Stone Men out of a sense of responsibility, then it could be said that 'Ser Jorah acquitted himself of his responsibility towards his prisoner'.

Comment: Why doesn't "acquit" make sense here? PS: Just figured out that you are A51FD!

Comment: @LittleEva: Yeah, I am. It's been a while since your last post, I guess. Changed my name as my Area 51 proposal isn't exactly making waves. Anyway, please see edit.